# How to make Networks not public?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-profile

How do I prevent the list of Networks that I've joined from being visible to the entire public?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this.

Leaving all networks might be your only option.

I would love to be proved wrong.